# Wrong character width when typesetting url with hyperref and a FakeStretch-ed font

Tags: xetex, fontspec, urls, typewriter

I just found out that hyperref does not really take the FakeStretch feature of fontspec into account :

**EDIT** This is actually a problem with the `url` package, which is used by `hyperref` to typeset urls.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}  %% or \usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}
\url{https://example.com}

\texttt{https://example.com}

\setmonofont[FakeStretch=.7]{Source Code Pro}
\url{https://example.com}

\texttt{https://example.com}

\end{document}
```

gives, with xelatex,

[image: result of code]

I browsed in the manual of hyperref and did not find a mention about this. I had the same problems with listings until I set the option `columns=flexible` instead of the default `fixed`.

Am I just clumsy ? Is this a bug in hyperref ? In fontspec ? Or am I just asking too much to these packages ?

Comment: It seems good when LuaLaTeX is used.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be specific to the xelatex implementation(s?).

Comment: `url` uses internally math, and xetex seems to be quite unwilling to use the FakeStretch/extend key with math fonts. Other keys like FakeSlant ot FakeBold works fine. It is not related to fontspec, one get the problem also with low-level commands. I don't see much one could do here beside switching to lualatex.

Comment: @Ulrike: this 'unwillingness' appears to be a weird feature or bug, no?